# Erro TrustLevel

Tags: asp.net

Minha aplicação hospedada na locaweb está com o seguinte erro:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Required permissions cannot be acquired.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Required
>   permissions cannot be acquired.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired.]
>   System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence,
>   PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset,
>   PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) +7613027
>   System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence,
>   PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset,
>   PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean
>   checkExecutionPermission) +57
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]    System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection) +0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +43
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +127
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +142    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +203    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +105
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +178
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath
>   configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
>   +54    System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +227
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +52
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +58    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
>   +729
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8979171
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +259

Eles falam que devo mudar minha aplicação para MediumTrustLevel mas não oferecem suporte algum para tal mudança falando apenas para consultar o programador. Ao pesquisar um pouco mais sobre, encontrei vários outros casos iguais mas sem solução, mas todos sugerem a alteração abaixo no **web.config**

Erro:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at
>   this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
>   to this section using  from an
>   inherited configuration file.

Tentativas que retornam o erro acima:

**Web.config**

1.

```
<system.web>
Line 38:     <trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />
Line 39:        <!--
Line 40:             Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
```

2.

```
Line 38:    <location allowOverride="true">
Line 39:        <system.web>
Line 40:            <securityPolicy>
Line 41:                <trust level="Medium" />
Line 42:            </securityPolicy>
```

3.

```
Line 38:    <location allowOverride="false">
Line 39:        <system.web>
Line 40:            <securityPolicy>
Line 41:                <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="internal" />
Line 42:            </securityPolicy>
```

Comment: Rodrigo, tive o mesmo problema na locaweb. Parece que algumas dll´s do .net 3.5 não são compatíveis com medium trust, também tentei alterar as configurações de medium trust sem sucesso, acredito que seja bloqueado, migrei minha aplicação para o .net 4.0 resolveu. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinceramente não tem muito o que fazer se você for ficar na Locaweb.

Se o seu site ainda está em uma fase inicial de desenvolvimento você pode configurar em seu Web.Config o trust level para medium, que é basicamente o que você encontrou em suas pesquisas, porém isso não vai resolver o problema, isso vai apenas te dar em tempo de desenvolvimento as mesmas limitações que a locaweb está impondo.

O que isso te ajuda é que você vai descobrir o que funciona ou não antes de enviar para a locaweb, porém pode esperar por muita frustração, muitas das tecnologias modernas não funcionam em medium trust, então nada de ASP.Net MVC, Entity Framework e provavelmente a maioria (se não todos) dos frameworks de IoC.

Se é um site que já estava funcionando e parou agora devido a mudança então estamos no mesmo barco, eu possuía um sistema a anos rodando na locaweb sem problemas e de um dia para o outro ele parou de funcionar devido a essa mudança, e foi algo sem nenhum aviso, simplesmente mudaram e só ao reclamar que fiquei sabendo da mudança de política deles, então eles voltaram o full trust e me deram 10 dias para corrigir o problema, depois disso voltariam para o medium trust.

Logo devo dizer que usei estes 10 dias muito bem para resolver todos os problemas com a locaweb, basicamente saindo dela, pois em 10 dias seria impossível mudar um site que já funcionava a quase 10 anos.

Se alguém me pedisse indicação de hospedagem a um ano atrás eu não teria duvidas em indicar a locaweb, hoje eu digo para ficar longe da locaweb.

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo, esse mesmo problema aconteceu comigo. Criei uma aplicação onde utilizei IoC com o Ninject, porém para que o Ninject funcione, a aplicação não pode ser configurada como MediumTrust, a locaweb não da suporte para FullTrust. Solucionei o problema mudando de hospedagem. Caso queira, eu posso informar para qual servidor de hospedagem eu migrei. Achei muito melhor que a locaweb.